# Woocommerce API v3 Images uploading issue

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using WooCommerce API v3 to upload product with a list of images. Images are uploaded and attached to the product successfully, it is shown in media library but not in product gallery. Please help me, you can check my screenshots below.

[Images are uploaded and attached to the product in media library page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xQfh.jpg)

[Images are not available in product gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYrST.jpg)

[This is the data that I have posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Slylv.jpg)

I am using python to make Woocommerce API call and this issue happens so many times.
I hope someone let me know what the issue is because it return no error message when I upload the product.

Comment: You are trying to link with src which is expected to be from the wp system not from 3rd party website. Try replacing the url with yourwebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/03/img name  also add the ID to prevent uploading same image over and over.